# Learning to rank in Information Retrieval

Tags: information-retrieval

Learning to rank is a machine learning based ranking framework.

How to implement learning to rank and also explain data pre-processing required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it is not a framework. it's a plugin for elasticsearch which enable machine learning to rescore top X results returned by elasticsearch query on the basis of defined features.

Here is it's official **[documention](http://elasticsearch-learning-to-rank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**

And here is a running **[demo](http://es-learn-to-rank.labs.o19s.com/demo/ltr-search.html)**, you can play with this it by cloning this **[github repo](https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank/tree/master/demo)**

I hope, it helps you.